# How can I make my cells align text to the left?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm making a table with HTML and CSS and I can't seem to get specific cells to align the text to the left.

Here is my table:

```
<table>
        <tr class="l0">
            <th rowspan="2">Employer/Employee Group</th>
            <th colspan="2">Duty</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Experience (Years)</th>
            <th rowspan="2">No. Of People</th>
            <th colspan="5">Responsibilities</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l0">
            <th>Permanent Duty</th>
            <th>As Required</th>
            <th>Job Training</th>
            <th>Product Quality</th>
            <th>Retention</th>
            <th>Human Resources</th>
            <th>Special Projects</th>
        </tr>


        <tr class="l2">
            <th colspan="10">US Army - Colorado Army National Guard</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Technicians/Soldiers</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2 - 6</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="l2">
            <th colspan="10">SPEC, Inc.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Administrative Staff</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td rowspan="4">5</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Engineers and Scientists</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Technicians</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Contract Technicians</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>> 20</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="l2">
            <th colspan="10">Radtec Engineering, Inc.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Administrative Staff</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td rowspan="4">4</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Engineers</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Technicians</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="l1">
            <td>Contractors</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My CSS has nothing saying to align center, only left yet the rows stay centered when I run it.

Here is my CSS:

```
 div.sqs-slice-group.copy.restrict-width-1000.text-align-center.align-center.align-center-absolute {
  top: 30px;
}

#main-navigation {
  word-spacing: 30px;
}

#footerBlocks {
  float: right; 
}

div.foo {
    float: right;       
}


table {
    width: 100%;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

/* Heading, odd and even lines for table shading */
tr.s0 {
    background: #B2B2B2;
}
tr.s1 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
tr.s2 {
    background: #E6E6E6;
}

/* Leadership Tables */
tr.l0 {
    background: #B2B2B2;
    text-align: left;
}
tr.l1 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
}
tr.l2 {
    background: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Could it be that table heading tags are centered by default?

Comment: Which cells are you speaking of? They all seem to be left aligned on my end: http://jsfiddle.net/pxhejLnk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it be that table heading tags are centered by default?

Centering (horizontal and vertical) a `<TH>` element's content is part of the recommendation in the [W3C's HTML 4.01 Specification section on tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.2):

> Visual user agents typically render TH elements vertically and horizontally centered within the cell and with a bold font weight.

To left justify, just add the following to your CSS:

```
th {
    text-align: left;
}
```

You can also do the following:

```
<td style="text-align:left">
```

Comment: wouldn't recommend a style attribute for this, why not just use css?

Comment: The style attribute is only there for completeness. Given how the CSS was structured in the question, I anticipate the OP using the CSS.

Comment: it's bad practice really, unless javascript puts it there, and even that's not really the best way either (classes are better), it's putting presentation information into the mark-up

Comment: Yes, I understand. I prefer the CSS approach and use it myself. My belief is that the OP and others would understand the difference. Are you saying that your preference is to withhold information?

Comment: yes, if it's not a good idea, as in something that has been proven to cause various problems down the line and is generally not advised by those are compiling best practices

Comment: My belief is that more knowledge is better and I like to believe that people will do the right thing. I actually think the style attribute can be useful for development purposes before moving it to the CSS.

Comment: it has it's place and I agree about more knowledge being better, but it doesn't pay to send someone down the wrong path, so I think suggesting things like that should at least come with a caveat, like 'only do this if you absolutely can't do it any other way'

Comment: One characteristic of SO is once an answer is accepted - if you edit it, the acceptance is lost. As mentioned, from the OP's description of the problem - I'm sure s/he will do the right thing. It's not the only or the first solution provided. And besides, there is this good discussion here now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<td align="left>...</td>
```

in the HTML?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp

Comment: very out of date information :-/ you'd add this potentially thousands of times to the HTML rather than `td { text-align:left; }` to the css?

Comment: Indeed, I misread his code, so I thought he tried this solution.